# How can I enable TCP/IPv4 Alternate Configuration with power shell on Win10?

Tags: powershell, tcp, windows-10, fallback

In Windows 10 you can set a fall back IP address if DHCP fails from the TCP/IPv4 properties window

[image]

I need to be able to enable and configure this via a power shell script.

I found this article on how to setup the IP address etc [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5362cd4-f1d8-4b25-9933-0523e80d5b0a/set-alternate-ip-configuration-to-static-values?forum=vbgeneral) and create a simple test script to alter the IP settings in the registry

```
# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Dhcp\Configurations\Alternate_{8B0F19CF-E766-4B8F-BB92-08C16D70CE5F}
$key = 'Registry::\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Dhcp\Configurations\Alternate_{8B0F19CF-E766-4B8F-BB92-08C16D70CE5F}'
$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name Options).Options
Write-Host $data

Write-Host 'Fallback:' $data[20] '.' $data[21] '.' $data[22] '.'$data[23]
Write-Host 'Subnet:  ' $data[44]'.'$data[45]'.'$data[46]'.'$data[47]
Write-Host 'Gatewyay:' $data[68]'.'$data[69]'.'$data[70]'.'$data[71]


# Update last two bytes of fall back
$data[22] = 8
$data[23] = 234

Write-Host 'Fallback:' $data[20] '.' $data[21] '.' $data[22] '.'$data[23]
set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name Options -Value $data
```

However what I can't figure out is how to programatically select the 'User Configured' settings.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find how to set this?  I need to do this on dozens of computers at my workplace.  I understand nothing in the link you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Further testing found that if I ran my script then rebooted the PC AND waited for the DCHP to time out, Windows would automatically switch to my new fallback IP